# "COPY failed: " While Building a Python Docker Image

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

I'm trying to create a Docker image using the following Dockerfile.

```
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /project4
COPY pythonCode1.py /project4/pythonCode1.py
COPY requirements.txt /project4/requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
CMD ["python3 ", "pythonCode1.py"]
```

I get the Error:

```
COPY failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat pythonCode1.py: file does not exist
```

I have not set up a .dockerignore file and I'm building in a directory that contains:

```
project4 
       |-- Dockerfile
       |-- pythonCode1.py
       |-- requirements.txt
```

I read some other posts that refered to the docker context, mine just had the default:

```
`default *   Current DOCKER_HOST based configuration   unix:///var/run/docker.sock swarm
```

Comment: where do you run the `docker build` command from and what does it look like? You'll have to run it from within the `project4` folder.

Comment: I run it from the directory project4. I use the command ```docker build - < Dockerfile```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by using

```sh
docker build - < Dockerfile
```

the Build Context does not include the whole dicrectory therefore the file `pythonCode1.py` is unknown to the Docker Engine.

Use the following docker build command instead.

```sh
# the . marks this directory as the directory with the Dockerfile and sets the build context 
docker build -t myrepo/myimage .
```

More information on build context and what it is and why it is required in this [blog post](https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/understanding-the-docker-build-context-why-you-should-use-dockerignore/).